# Select multiple columns from MySql to Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySql database which contains a `VARCHAR` field (called `nev` here) and a couple `INT`s

[image: database]

What I want is select all of the integers which columns contains 'w' (w0, w1 etc) and put it into an array or an `ArrayList`. And also select those which has 'b' in the columns. And I want to only select those values whose has a specific 'nev' which comes from another class.

Here is my code so far:

```
public static Connection qry(){
        Connection qry=null;
        try {
           qry=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feladat","admin","admin");    
           String query ="SELECT * FROM pontszamok WHERE nev="+GUI.selected;
           Statement st2;
           st2 = qry.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = st2.executeQuery(query);          

            while (rs.next())
            {


            }
            st2.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return qry;
```

What should be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how you get the values of the column `w0` and `nev` and store them into a `List`, you can do the same way for all the columns you want

```
List<Integer> myValuesW0 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> myValuesNev = new ArrayList<String>();

while (rs.next())
{
     myValuesW0.add(rs.getInt("w0")); //the name of the column not the value
     myValuesNev.add(rs.getString("nev")); //for String Values
     .
     .
     //the same treatment for the rest
}
```

Also you have an error in your query, since "nev" is a `varchar` type, so you have to apply single quotation marks  ( `' '` ) on the value this way:

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM pontszamok WHERE nev= '"+GUI.selected+"' ";
```

or you can use this method too:

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM pontszamok WHERE nev= ? ";
query.setParameter(1, GUI.selected);
//replace the first question mark (?) with the variable GUI.selected
//this way you can avoid being confused between the quotation marks
```

Comment: Thanks! When I run the query got this error message: "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Test' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @Ballazx it's an error in your code, now it should be fixed with the edited answer. please check it now

Answer (score 0):

If the column is `int` type, you can get them by

```
rs.getInt("column-name");
```